# How do I add a toolbar item .net maui?

Tags: c#, .net, shell, toolbar, maui

As the question states I am trying to add a toolbar item/button to shell for adding a database item.
Normally in Xamarin forms I was able to add a toolbar item with

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add"
                 Clicked="AddItem_Clicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

But I have not figured out how to make this work in .net maui, does anyone have any insight on this?
So far I have a shell with flyout menu but I would like to add an "Add" button to the top right corner.

If there was a way to do this on the Shell menu that would be more preferred than the page level but either would be great.

Edit: I was able to get it working with help from the first comment below but I am unable to make adjustments to button width or have it in a stacklayout, so code looks like:

```
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Button Text="+" Clicked="AddItem_Clicked" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" MaximumWidthRequest="20" WidthRequest="20"></Button>
    </Shell.TitleView>
```

Adding a stacklayout around the button makes it not show up anymore. Also this does not work on Windows build as nothing shows up.
[image]

Comment: Checking my code, yours doesn't make the button fully positioned.

Comment: Did this ever work for you?

Comment: My size was successfully limited.

Comment: I have the same issue using https://github.com/irongut/MauiBeach/tree/master/src/MauiBeach

Comment: Hey, I have just been trying to place anything in the shell title view and it looks like at your screen - in a weird place and really hard to actually show anything there. Setting a margin has very weird consequences. I've tried a lot of things and none of them worked. I think this might be a bug in the preview build. Hopefully it will be solved soon.

Comment: Well good to hear its not just me. I hope they fix it soon that would be awesome. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Well since I tried it yesterday on latest .net maui release it looks like toolbar items are working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must have been a .net maui bug in the preview version. Toolbar item appears to be working just fine now.

Comment: I just updated to the new Visual Studio preview version, but it still doesn't work. :( I have the same problem...

Comment: Assuming you tried using the toolbar items approach as instead of shell.titleview? That is what did it for me. I haven't gone back and tried titleview since.

Comment: This is not an answer. An answer should not be contain "should", "must", "i guess" etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **Shell.TitleView** to achieve the above page add function.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="ADD" Clicked="Button_Clicked" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="End"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

For more information, please refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/pages#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar

Comment: It definitely shows up but not when its in the stack layout. Also width request not working for some reason. A very good start though thank you, that definitely gets the add button in the top -- now I just need to figure out why adjustments to the button aren't working.

Comment: It may be caused by other codes, or change to another emulator.

Comment: This is only for the main shell page how do I get one to work on other pages before I would have used toolbaritem? @WenxuLi-MSFT

Comment: @c-sharp-and-swiftui-devni I have this working with `ToolBarItems`; please see my answer for more details.

Comment: Thank you!  This save me the continued grief of trying to resolve my need for conditional render of ToolbarItem, which does not have an IsVisible property. Using the TitleView I have solved.

Answer (score 3):

Use Shell Toolbar Items, something like this :

```
 <Shell.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Settings"
                     Priority="1"
                     Order="Secondary"
                     Command="{Binding NavigateToSettingsPageCommand}"/>

        <ToolbarItem Text="Profile"
                     Priority="2"
                     Order="Secondary"
                     Command="{Binding NavigateToProfilePageCommand}"/>

        <ToolbarItem Text="Share App"
                     Priority="3"
                     Order="Secondary"
                     Command="{Binding NavigateToShareAppCommand}"/>

        <ToolbarItem Text="Log Out"
                     Priority="4"
                     Order="Secondary"
                     Command="{Binding LogOutCommand}"/>
    </Shell.ToolbarItems>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well -

- Had app based on a previous Xamarin sample
- Create new item `ContentPage` had `ToolBarItems`:

  ```
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
      <ToolbarItem Text="Cancel" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked" />
      <ToolbarItem Text="Save" Clicked="Save_Clicked" />
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  ```
- Neither `ToolBarItems` nor `TitleView` were showing at all
- Was navigating to page using the following:

  ```
  await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new NewActivityPage()));
  ```

Per [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage):

> `NavigationPage` is incompatible with .NET MAUI Shell apps, and an exception will be thrown if you attempt to use `NavigationPage` in a Shell app. For more information about Shell apps, see [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/).

I fixed this referencing the above notice's [.NET MAUI Shell overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/) and its accompanying [Xaminals sample](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/6.0/Fundamentals/Shell).

Changes made:

- Added the following route registration to AppShell.xaml.cs:

  ```
  public Dictionary<string, Type> Routes { get; private set; } = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

  private void RegisterRoutes()
  {
      this.Routes.Add("newactivity", typeof(NewActivityPage));

      foreach (var item in this.Routes)
      {
          Routing.RegisterRoute(item.Key, item.Value);
      }
  }
  ```
- Called route registration from `AppShell` ctor, after `InitializeComponent`
- Navigated to page using the following:

  ```
  await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("newactivity");
  ```

My understanding is that the `NavigationPage` method I was using was not working, per the docs, and that using Shell navigation correctly now has it working as expected.